PiKVM V2 MOSFET relays
I need some IP-KVM's for my homelab, so I decided to build 3 PiKVM's following this guide from the official docs. I almost got all the parts and designed a custom PCB for the ATX controller, which I can manufacture on the CNC mill.
The only parts missing are those Omron G3VM-61A1's or G3VM-61AY1's. The A1 is obsolete and shipping on those AY1's might take up to 26 weeks, since they are out of stock everywhere.
Is there an alternative I can use? I never worked with solid-state relays, so I need some assistance picking the correct parts. They are basically used as glorified PC power and reset buttons.

I don't know what you're building, but G3VM-61VY3 seem very similar except the package (SOP4 vs. DIP). Lots (tens of thousands) in stock at LCSC & Mouser.
Generally superior or equal in most ways (sensitivity is much higher ,on resistance lower, off leakage lower) except can be a bit slower to turn off.
If you need the DIP package there are probably other makers with that kind of legacy packaging

Thanks for the quick response! I got some of those 61VY3's now. They are very much overkill for my application anyways, since they are just used as switches connected to GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi 4. Do I understand correctly that you literally just apply a voltage to one side and they close the circuit on the other? (literally complete beginner here. I know how to use resistors and wires, but I'm actually a software person :)

You pass a current through the LED, typically via a voltage with a series resistor, and the other side closes like a switch. The switch and LED are electrically isolated so there is no need to worry about how grounds are connected and that sort of thing, which is why they were probably chosen in this application. Don't apply a voltage without a series resistor or the LED can be destroyed.

@Caeleste The Electrical schematic diagram for advanced users in Setting up the hardware shows 390 ohm series resistors being used for the LEDs on the suggested 61A1 opto-couplers.
